# Center SeekBar and ImageButton in RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I have the following xml:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/reset" 
        android:onClick="reset"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/reset" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried using `gravity="center"` and `layout_gravity="center"` but it didn't work. How do I center the contents of RelativeLayout?

Comment: where did you apply the layout_gravitiy property?

Comment: layout_gravity will set the gravity of the RelativeLayout in its parent.

Comment: can you please put screen shot for your requirement, i'm not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of those three for relative layout:

1. [android:layout_centerHorizontal](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_centerHorizontal)  set to true
2. [android:layout_centerVertical](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_centerVertical) set to true
3. [android:layout_centerInParent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_centerInParent) set to true

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/reset"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/reset" 
    android:onClick="reset"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/reset"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  />
</RelativeLayout>
```